# Firebase rules with custom IDs on nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've been trying to create some rules for my firebase database, but it seems like I'm hitting a brick wall or (hopefully) there's just some point I'm not getting.

My data structure looks something like this:

```
units
    <custom user id eg. 1234>
        unit1
        unit2
        ...
users
    <custom user id eg. 1234>
        name
        email
        phone
        ...
node3
    <custom user id eg. 1234>
        object1
        object2
        ...
```

What I'd like to do is create rules that will only allow the user with ID 1234 (which is obviously different than the user's uid in Firebase authentication) to access his nodes.

Is there some way I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  There is a page on per-user security rules.  It describes everything you need to know.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't seem to work when I've created the nodes with "custom" ids rather than let firebase create them dynamically?

Comment: Edit the question to show the rules that don't work the way you expect, along with the code that accesses your database.  You'll need to make it clear to us what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why are you not using Firebase Authentication user UID instead of custom UID but ok :)

If you have mapping somewhere in your database between Firebase Authentication UID and your custom UID (e.g. you have saved Firebase Auth UID for user 1234 in mapping/1234/authUID), then you can write the database rule like this:

```
"users": {
    "$customUserUid": {
        ".write": "root.child('mapping').child($customUserUid).child('authUID').val() === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like just the hint I need, many thanks! :)
EDIT: The reason behind the custom UIDs is unfortunately out of my hands

Comment: But for the first time while creating a new user using this rule trick it is throwing the error Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(-3, Permission denied, )

Please help